# URL rewrite for DomainName.com

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am doing a rewrite for url www.DomainName.com/x. If any user types in

1. DomainName.com/x or
2. DomainName.com/x/

it must go to exit.php, where "x" can be anything.

My Code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /$ exit.php
RwriteRule $ exit.php
```

How do I write the rewrite code for it to go to exit.php and when DomainName.com is typed it should go to DomainName.com not exit.php

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Do you have an actual question, or are you just posting a series of facts?

Comment: @ Greg @Jon
Question is placed

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(|start\.php)$ start.php [L] #Contains the filename you want to redirect when calling www.domain.tld/
RewriteRule .+ exit.php [L]
```

Comment: It works, but when I type in DomainName.com/ it goes to exit.php

Comment: when i type DomainName.com it should go to index.php

Comment: Think about the patterns above and try to modify them. There are not so many possible changes...! Sometimes comments are also interesting, so read the comments in my code snippet too!