# Keeping the original subdomain url in the address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

How can I change my rewrite rule to keep the original subdomain url in the address bar?

Currently if it type in "username.domain.com"    it gets redirected to    "domain.com/username"...and I would like the address bar to stay at "username.domain.com".

I'm using wildcard subdomains with this rewrite rule in my httpd.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule . http://domain.com/sites/%2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Serverfault. It is BTW quite possible, especially if you use mod_proxy. But even with mod_rewrite only, it should be...

Comment: thanks, i've created my account at server vault and posted it there.

Comment: Have a look at my posting in another topic to have a proxy example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984483/url-rewrite-for-domainname-com/4984497#4984497